# Second form on page is using first form's action attribute

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a page with two forms, and the second form is using the action attribute of the first form. Code:

```
<!-- mountain sites -->
<form name="form" action="shopsite.php" method="post" id="form">

<!-- sites pass alt tag to shopsite.php -->
<ul id="sites">
<tr>
<li><td class="" id="Hyland"><div><img id="imgHyland" onclick="this.src='radiotower.jpg';clearAck('Hyland');" src="radiotower.jpg" alt="Hyland" class="location" /><br/>Hyland</div></td></li>

</ul>
<div><input type="hidden" name="sitename" id="sitename" value="" /></div>
</form><!-- end first form -->


<!-- non-mountain sites -->
<form name="form-nm" action="shopsite-nm.php" method="post" id="form-nm">

<!-- sites pass alt tag to shopsite-nm.php -->
<ul id="sites">
<li><td class="" id="KMS"><div><img id="imgKMS" onclick="this.src='radiotower.jpg';clearAck('KMS');" src="radiotower.jpg" alt="KMS" class="location" /><br/>KMS</div></td></li>
</tr>
<div><input type="hidden" name="sitename" id="sitename" value="" /></div>
</form><!-- end second form -->
```

When I click an input on either form (inputs are the li tags), it goes to shopsite.php. Inputs in the second form should go to shopsite-nm.php. I researched using multiple forms on a page to call different php pages, and supposedly it's possible, although the example I found did not use a hidden input. I'm not sure if that could be the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Edit: the sitename is passing correctly from both forms.

Edit 2: if there's a better way to construct this, I'm open to suggestions. The idea is that each form displays a list of sites with their status, and when the user clicks on a site, they are shown a page with more detailed information about that particular site. There was originally just one form with all the sites, but new sites have recently been added that require a different informational display, which is what I'm now trying to accommodate with the second form.

Comment: An aside: Your second edit was a smart addition -- it is the kind of information that helps avoid the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: what does `clearAck()` do? does this submit the form? sidenote: you can use a submit button and use an attribute `form="your_form_id"`, it sets what form it should submit, `<input type="submit" name="submit" form="form-nm" />`

Comment: clearAck() does not submit the form; it sets a bit that says the user has acknowledged a previously existing problem so that it doesn't continue to display an error message.

The reason I'm not using a submit button is that each li displays an image (the src parameter) and the user clicks on that, so the image is the button. The display is going to be viewed on a large screen from a distance, so larger inputs are encouraged, as buttons will be hard to read.

Comment: You've got multiple elements with the same id (e.g, `sites`, `sitename`, etc.) This is bad — ids need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use JQuery here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Hyland').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'shopsite.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(res) {
                //Do Something here
                console.log(res);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                //Do Something here
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    });
});
```